# R -- Can I apply the train function in caret to a list of data frames?

Tags: r, machine-learning, r-caret, mapply

I am using the excellent R package, caret, and I'd like to run the train function on a list of multiple training data sets. Now, I realize the documentation for the train function says that the data argument must be a data frame, so what I'm trying to do simply may not be possible and this might better be suggested as an enhancement to caret, but I wanted to see if anyone had tried to do this.

Using the Sonar data for illustrative purposes, I've created a list (named both) consisting of two data frames, each of which is a separate training dataset. I'm then using mapply to apply the train function to each element in the list. Unfortunately, I'm getting scary-looking results. Specifically, I was hoping that the metrics in pls1.3..A[[2]] would be identical to the metrics in pls1.3..B2. As you can see, they are not. Oddly, pls1.3..A[[1]] match pls1.3..B1. Is there something obvious I'm doing wrong, or might this just not be possible (now)? (I'm running R 3.1.1 on a 1.4 GHz Intel Core i5 Mac.)

Reproducible code (and output commented out) follows:

```
    require(doMC)
    registerDoMC(cores = 2) 

    library(caret) 
    library(mlbench) 
    data(Sonar) 
    set.seed(1234) 
    inTrain <- createDataPartition(y = Sonar$Class, 
                                   p = .75, 
                                    list = FALSE) 

    training <- Sonar[ inTrain,] 
    training2  <- Sonar[-inTrain,] 

    both <- list(training, training2) 
    #both_test <- list(training[c(1:100),], training2[c(1:35),]) #SILLY test data for functionality testing only 

    set.seed(1234) 

    labels <- list() 
    for(i in 1:length(both)) { 
        labels[i] <- list(both[[i]]$Class) 
        } 

    #NEW CODE -- ADDED BASED ON @Josh W's comment -- removing the label (Class) variable from the feature matrix
    both <- lapply(both, function(x) {
        subset(x[,c(1:60)])
        })

    #NEW CODE -- changed from using the formula implementation of caret to the x (feature matrix), y (label/outcome vector)

    pls1.3..A <- mapply(function(x,y) train(x, y, method = "pls", preProc = c("center", "scale")), x = both, y = labels, SIMPLIFY = FALSE) 
    pls1.3..A 

    #[[1]]
    #Partial Least Squares 

    #157 samples
    # 60 predictor
    #  2 classes: 'M', 'R' 

    #Pre-processing: centered, scaled 
    #Resampling: Bootstrapped (25 reps) 

    #Summary of sample sizes: 157, 157, 157, 157, 157, 157, ... 

    #Resampling results across tuning parameters:

    #  ncomp  Accuracy   Kappa      Accuracy SD  Kappa SD  
    #  1      0.6889679  0.3756821  0.06015197   0.11605511
    #  2      0.7393776  0.4742204  0.04962609   0.09775688
    #  3      0.7410997  0.4793703  0.04856698   0.09412599

    #Accuracy was used to select the optimal model using  the largest value.
    #The final value used for the model was ncomp = 3. 

    #[[2]]
    #Partial Least Squares 

    #51 samples
    #60 predictors
    # 2 classes: 'M', 'R' 

    #Pre-processing: centered, scaled 
    #Resampling: Bootstrapped (25 reps) 

    #Summary of sample sizes: 51, 51, 51, 51, 51, 51, ... 

    #Resampling results across tuning parameters:

    #  ncomp  Accuracy   Kappa      Accuracy SD  Kappa SD 
    #  1      0.6452693  0.2929118  0.08076455   0.1525176
    #  2      0.6468405  0.2902136  0.09686340   0.1790924
    #  3      0.6559113  0.3087227  0.08025215   0.1547317

    #Accuracy was used to select the optimal model using  the largest value.
    #The final value used for the model was ncomp = 3.          

    set.seed(1234)
    pls1.3..B1 <- train(both[[1]],
                    labels[[1]],
                    method = "pls",
                    preProc = c("center", "scale"))
    pls1.3..B1
    #Partial Least Squares 

    #157 samples
    # 60 predictor
    #  2 classes: 'M', 'R' 

    #Pre-processing: centered, scaled 
    #Resampling: Bootstrapped (25 reps) 

    #Summary of sample sizes: 157, 157, 157, 157, 157, 157, ... 

    #Resampling results across tuning parameters:

    #  ncomp  Accuracy   Kappa      Accuracy SD  Kappa SD  
    #  1      0.6889679  0.3756821  0.06015197   0.11605511
    #  2      0.7393776  0.4742204  0.04962609   0.09775688
    #  3      0.7410997  0.4793703  0.04856698   0.09412599

    #Accuracy was used to select the optimal model using  the largest value.
    #The final value used for the model was ncomp = 3. 

    set.seed(1234)
    pls1.3..B2 <- train(both[[2]],
                    labels[[2]],
                    method = "pls",
                    preProc = c("center", "scale"))
    pls1.3..B2

    #Partial Least Squares 

    #51 samples
    #60 predictors
    # 2 classes: 'M', 'R' 

    #Pre-processing: centered, scaled 
    #Resampling: Bootstrapped (25 reps) 

    #Summary of sample sizes: 51, 51, 51, 51, 51, 51, ... 

    #Resampling results across tuning parameters:

    #  ncomp  Accuracy   Kappa      Accuracy SD  Kappa SD 
    #  1      0.6127279  0.2518488  0.11925682   0.1959400
    #  2      0.6792163  0.3618657  0.09386771   0.1776549
    #  3      0.6673662  0.3343716  0.07524373   0.1476405

    #Accuracy was used to select the optimal model using  the largest value.
    #The final value used for the model was ncomp = 2.
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use the following, you'll get the result (close to what) you expect:

```
set.seed(1234) 
pls1.3..B <- train(labels[[2]]~ ., 
                   data = both[[2]], 
                   method = "pls", 
                   preProc = c("center", "scale")) 
pls1.3..B
```

I believe it's because of the way you have the formula specified. `object ~ .` has the formula use everything in the data that's not the column `object`. Specified in the mapply call, it's `basically external object ~ entire data.frame`, including Class labels. So I believe it's like training with your response variable in the dataset.

Comment: Josh W -- very good point. I've edited the code to eliminate this problem by removing the outcome column from the list named "both." Doing this, corrects a definite error. Thanks. Unfortunately, it does not resolve the problem as my edited post shows.