# Caret train function for muliple data frames as function

Tags: r, function, r-caret, caret

there has been a similar question to mine 6 years+ ago and it hasn't been solve ([R -- Can I apply the train function in caret to a list of data frames?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30552403/r-can-i-apply-the-train-function-in-caret-to-a-list-of-data-frames))
This is why I am bringing up this topic again.

I'm writing my own functions for my big R project at the moment and I'm wondering if there is an opportunity to sum up the model training function `train()` of the pakage `caret` for different dataframes with different predictors.
My function should look like this:

```
lda_ex <- function(data, predictor){
   model <- train(predictor ~., data,
      method = "lda",
      trControl = trainControl(method = "none"),
      preProc = c("center","scale"))
   return(model)
}
```

Using it afterwards should work like this:

```
data_iris <- iris
predictor_iris <- "Species"

iris_res <- lda_ex(data = data_iris, predictor = predictor_iris)
```

Unfortunately the R formula is not able to deal with a variable as input as far as I tried.

Is there something I am missing?
Thank you in advance for helping me out!

Solving this would help me A LOT to keep my function sheet clean and safe work for sure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By writing `predictor_iris <- "Species"`, you are basically saving a string object in `predictor_iris`. Thus, when you run `lda_ex`, I guess you incur in some error concerning the `formula` object in `train()`, since you are trying to predict a string using vectors of covariates.

Indeed, I tried the following toy example:

```
X = rnorm(1000)
Y = runif(1000)

predictor = "Y"

lm(predictor ~ X)
```

which gives an error about differences in the lengths of variables.

Let me modify your function:

```
lda_ex <- function(data, formula){
  model <- train(formula, data,
                 method = "lda",
                 trControl = trainControl(method = "none"),
                 preProc = c("center","scale"))
  return(model)
}
```

The key difference is that now we must pass in the whole `formula`, instead of the predictor only. In that way, we avoid the string-related problem.

```
library(caret) # Recall to specify the packages needed to reproduce your examples!

data_iris <- iris
formula_iris = Species ~ . # Key difference!
iris_res <- lda_ex(data = data_iris, formula = formula_iris)
```

Comment: unfortunately it is giving the same error of differences in the lengths of variables with the modification you offered

Comment: Ops, I made a mistake in my answer. I am going to edit it.

Comment: Thank you so so much!!! It works! So excited 'bout this :)!

Comment: I am pleased to hear this :) Consider to upvote and accept my question, if you feel your problem is solved :)